# Custom calendar view in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I'm building a custom calendar view for my android app that allows you to swipe between months. I've created custom calendar square views, which I've embedded into a custom calendar *month* view, and everything is working perfectly on the 1-month scale.

Unfortunately, now I'm stuck. I now want to embed my custom calendar month views into an infinite view pager, so that I can scroll forward and backward through the calendar indefinitely.

I've tried adapting [this horizontal pager](https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager) for infinite scrolling by using a simple trick. I hold an array of 3 of my calendar month views and update the list based on where the user scrolls to. Example...

1. [July, **August**, September] (focus is on August, then user swipes to September)
2. [July, August, **September**] (focus is now on September)
3. [*August*, August, **September**] (shift August left by one, overwriting July)
4. [August, *September*, **September**] (shift September left by one, overwriting August)
5. [August, **September**, September] (set the view to the middle September, so we're centered again)
6. [August, **September**, *October*] (overwrite the 2nd September with the actual next month)

When I do this, though, there's a noticeable flash on the screen when swiping to the next month.

Here's the code for forward scrolling (note: backward scrolling has the same issue)

```
private void updateViewsForForwardScroll() {
    // Note: INDEX_PREV = 0; INDEX_CURR = 1; INDEX_NEXT = 2
    ((CalendarMonthView) getChildAt(INDEX_PREV)).showMonth(oneMonthPriorTo(currentMonth));
    ((CalendarMonthView) getChildAt(INDEX_CURR)).showMonth(currentMonth);
    setCurrentScreen(INDEX_CURR, false);
    ((CalendarMonthView) getChildAt(INDEX_NEXT)).showMonth(oneMonthAfter(currentMonth));
}
```

I think the problem is that setCurrentScreen() finishes before showMonth(currentMonth), so the view at INDEX_CURR is still updating when the screen is set. I tried solving that by using the following strategy instead...

1. [July, **August**, September] (focus is on August, then user swipes to September)
2. [July, August, **September**] (focus is now on September)
3. [August, **September**] (remove July, but store it for recycling)
4. [August, **September**, October] (recycle July to instead display October, and add the view)

I haven't touched the currently focused view at all, but there's still a flash! This time, the screen flashes from September, to August, then back to September.

So **what am I doing wrong?** Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do without the user knowing about it? If not, is there an existing class I can leverage?

(As a side question, is there any way I can customize the Android CalendarView visually? That would really solve all my problems...)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using the native [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) and [`PagerAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html) classes for this? [Example here](http://code.google.com/p/viewpagerexample/source/browse/trunk/AwesomePager/src/com/geekyouup/paug/awesomepager/AwesomePagerActivity.java). It looks like it will give you more flexibility as far as adding/removing the `View`s as the user swipes.

Comment: @user113215 I did try these at one point but ran into similar issues. I'm planning on giving it another go though, however I'm confused as to what I should return from `getCount()`, and how to handle functions that take `position` as a parameter. What do count and position mean in an infinite list?

Comment: Well, position could mean "months since the beginning of the common era", if you needed to go back that far. Start at position 24153, meaning this month. `getCount` could return the starting position * 2 or something like this.

Comment: Or limit it to 100 years ago to 100 years forward. In any case, it won't be truly infinite.

Comment: Good point! I'll try this soon. Thanks!

Comment: @user113215 your suggestion actually solved all of my problems. If you pose your comment as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Glad to help. Actually, you should post how you ended up doing it and accept your own answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting it to work by extending `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, and also integrating user113215's suggestion. I didn't go for truly infinite scrolling, but rather virtually infinite (i.e. 10,000 months, or 833 years). Here's the bulk of my code:

```
public static class CalendarAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private static final int NUM_MONTHS = 10000;
    private static final int INDEX_EPOCH = NUM_MONTHS/2;
    private static final int MONTHS_PER_YEAR = 12;
    private static final Calendar calendarMonthEpoch = new GregorianCalendar(2012, Calendar.AUGUST, 1);

    // ...

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_MONTHS;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return CalendarMonthFragment.newInstance(calendarMonthAtPosition(position));
    }

    private static Calendar calendarMonthAtPosition(int position) {
        int offset = position - INDEX_EPOCH;
        Calendar calMonthAtPosition = (Calendar) calendarMonthEpoch.clone(); 
        calMonthAtPosition.add(Calendar.MONTH, offset % MONTHS_PER_YEAR);
        calMonthAtPosition.add(Calendar.YEAR, offset / MONTHS_PER_YEAR);

        return calMonthAtPosition;
    }

    // ...

}
```